# How do you prevent duplicates from entering list using setdefault in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose you have a dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[1,2]}
```

And suppose the next item is `{b:2}`. I don't want there to be any repeats in the values of my dictionary for all keys. So `{b:2}` would not update the dictionary, but `{b:3}` would update it as:

```
{'a':[1,2], 'b':[1,2,3]}
```

I would like to make some alteration to the `setdefault` method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your dict1 values to `set`.

```
In [44]: dict1 = {'a':[1,2],'b':[1,2]}

In [45]: dict1 = {k: set(v) for k, v in dict1.items()}

In [46]: def add_to_dict(dict_tmp):
    ...:     for k, v in dict_tmp.items():
    ...:         dict1.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
    ...:     return dict1
    ...:

In [47]: d2 = {'b':2}

In [48]: d3 = {'b':3}

In [49]: add_to_dict(d2)
Out[49]: {'a': {1, 2}, 'b': {1, 2}}

In [50]: add_to_dict(d3)
Out[50]: {'a': {1, 2}, 'b': {1, 2, 3}}
```

The function `add_to_dict` returns a dict with value as `set`. If your requirement is such that you need the values as `list` you can modify dict values at the end.

Comment: Cool, I like that solution.

Comment: @fredrussell Glad it helped. You can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.

Comment: @fredrussell that requirement is for upvote, no such requirement  for accepting the answer.You can accept answer by clicking that tick mark just below upvote counts. :)